# Installation of GLPK

Tags: installation, gnupg, glpk

I have tried installing GLPK in my Windows 10 64 bit OS but failed as the steps are literally confusing.

These were the steps given in the official website :

> **Downloading GLPK**
>
> The GLPK distribution tarball can be found on http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/ [via http] and
>   ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/ [via FTP].  It can also be found on one of
>   our FTP mirrors; please use a mirror if possible. To make sure that
>   the GLPK distribution tarball you have downloaded is intact you need
>   to download the corresponding .sig file and run a command like this:
>   `gpg --verify glpk-4.32.tar.gz.sig` If that command fails because you do
>   not have the required public key, run the following command to import
>   it: `gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 5981E818` and then
>   re-run the previous command.

I have downloaded both the files but when I enter the command in the cmd prompt it throws an error saying that "**gpg is not an internal or external command,operable program or batch file"**.

The installation is so complex that I am unable to figure out.If anyone who has already installed,could help me on the steps,so that I'll be really grateful to them.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Of course it's hard to install software from sources without any knowledge of the common tools. The error above just tells you, that you don't have gpg installed or gpg is not in PATH. Of course you could skip that hash-check (if you trust the source) but i think you will run into many other much harder to debug problems. [There are also ready windows-builds available](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/files/winglpk/GLPK-4.60/). You need to compile from sources?

Answer (score 0):

There are several Use-Cases of GLPK and there are different less complicated approaches of installing the parts of GLPK you really need.

**Case A**: You like to edit the source code of GLPK, change the way GLPK behaves or would like to compile GLPK with some special settings for your special hardware.

For this you will need the sources you are referring and you will also need a development environment to handle/compile these files (**complicated**)

**Case B**: You want to use the keyfunctions out of the box, link them to your own application or use the standalone solver (to call it from commandline or for example python)

You can get (as sascha already mentioned) precompiled binarys like Winglpk (for Windows), they include ready to use .exe and .dll files (**not that complicated**)

**Case C**: You have an optimization problem and you just want to define the problem and solve it. You are not interested in building some sort of application.

Have a look at [Gusek](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gusek) it comes with an interface for mathprog (ampl like modelling language), a precompiled GLPK version and the comfort of just having to click "Go" to solve your defined model (**easy**)

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to build GLPK from source. You could use GLPK for Windows available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/. It provides 32bit and 64bit Windows binaries.

Just download the file and unzip it.